# Shared memory and pointers

Tags: c, pointers, heap-memory, shared-memory

Two processes (or programs) are using the same *System V* shared memory segment,
which is basically this struct

```
/* file: shmem.h */
struct Shmem{
    int *array;
}
```

From program1 I initialize the shared memory like this

```
/* file: program1.c */
Shmem_init(shmem, siz);
for (int i=0; i<siz; i++)
    shmem->array[i] = number;
```

where `Shmem_init` is implemented like this

```
/* file: shmem.c */
void Shmem_init(Shmem *shmem, int siz){
    shmem->array = (int *)malloc(siz * sizeof(int));
}
```

Then if I try to access `shmem->array[i]` from program2, my program just freezes and does nothing(undefined behavior?)

Should I have expected that? Is it because the elements `array[1], array[2], ...`
are stored in program1's heap and therefore are not accesible by program2?

Thanks

[ Don't mind about stuff like `shmget()` and `shmat()`, those are taken care of ]

Comment: So you're just using malloc and that's it? That's not how you create shared memory

Comment: No I know how to use `shmget` and those functions, that's not the point of this post

Comment: So what is? You haven't shown how you use the shared memory or how the code relates to the topic. Please explain more. How do you try to access it from another process?

Comment: @DaMike You can't share memory that you got from malloc. What are you having issue with ? If you want to share your arrey pointer in the Shmem struct, you cannot use malloc.

Comment: @nos I just want to have an array in my shmem struct, where I don't know the size of it at compile time. The user defines the size. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You answered your own question... The pointer returned by malloc is only valid for the process that called it.

Comment: Thx I just wanted to be sure!

Comment: are you sure? I used to create data in the heap in a native process and use it from managed process. I do not think it is the problem

Comment: @HumamHelfawi - *are you sure? I used to create data in the heap in a native process and use it from managed process. I do not think it is the problem*  Please post that code.

Comment: @HumamHelfawi yes, quite sure. You shouldn't really be using raw pointers when using SHM, rather offsets from the address the SHM is mapped to by each process using it. If your code works it's probably a complete fluke.

Comment: I would do it tomorrow morning if you are interested (it is on my work machine). However, it is very common pattern let me find you some link for now

Comment: @James I do not think it fluke I have many products with this pattern that have been working for a while without any tiny problem

Comment: @HumamHelfawi that is not the type of shared memory OP is asking about. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_memory#Support_on_Unix-like_systems

Comment: the example may be not suitable.. in short words, I create for example an array of structs in C++ using new keyword and return its address to c# programm which is deal use it as IntPtr and marshal it to another managed objects and may alter it and allocated an unmanaged block and send the address to the c++ part again.. everything were done smoothly

Comment: How is any of that relevent to a question on C? You're wrong if you think this answers OP's question.

Comment: Mnay are telling that it is impossible, I am in doubt that I did not understand the question at all..

Comment: I just used it as example of allocating memory in heap and using it from another place.. it is abit related.. is not it ?

Comment: You seem to think that returning memory from a DLL is the same as interprocess communication via shm files. It isn't.

Comment: I see.. Thanks for notifying I am going to read about it.. withdrawing my downvote. you may edit your answer for formatting issue for example :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't give details on your code, i'm assuming you are using boost shared memory. And you are using the [example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/interprocess/sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.html#interprocess.sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.sharedmemory.shared_memory_a_simple_example) in the docs.

```
//////////////////
/// first process
#define COUNT 1000
//Set size
shm.truncate(COUNT*sizeof(int) + sizeof(int)); //COUNT*sizeof(data type) + sizeof(shmem_size)

mapped_region region(shm, read_write);

int *size = static_cast<int*> (region.get_address());
*size = COUNT;
Shmem *mem = reinterpret_cast<Shmem*>(size+1);
... // fill mem->array

//////////////////
/// second process
//Map the whole shared memory in this process
mapped_region region(shm, read_only);

int size = *static_cast<int*> (region.get_address());
Shmem *mem = reinterpret_cast<Shmem*>(static_cast<int*>(region.get_address())+1);
```

Comment: Ehm actually I'm using _system V_  shared memory segments. Sorry, I didn't add details in my post.

Comment: I don't know about it, but the idea should apply to it too. allocate a buffer from the shared memory, cast it to your struct and fill it. In the other process, access to the same memory, cast it to your struct and read/write whatever you want.

Comment: The first version had bugs, I fixed it.